Dependency of navigation-compose failed to sync on Compose Multiplatform project
I was building a desktop application using Compose Multiplatform and I need a navigation.
I followed the guides and added a dependency of androidx.navigation:navigation-compose with version 2.7.7.
// /gradle/libs.versions.toml
[versions]
compose = "1.6.2"
compose-plugin = "1.6.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
kotlin = "1.9.22"
kotlin-serialization-json = "1.6.3"
ktor = "2.3.10"
coroutines = "1.8.0"
nav = "2.6.0"

[libraries]
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-test-junit = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "kotlin-serialization-json" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
compose-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-nav = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "nav" }
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-engine = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktor" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "coroutines" }

[plugins]
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinSerialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }

// /composeApp/build.gradle.kts
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinSerialization)

    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
}

kotlin {
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
//            implementation(kotlin.serialization.json)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.engine)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
            implementation(libs.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
            implementation(libs.compose.nav)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}


compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.myproject"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

But when I sync it with Android Studio, I got errors as below.
:composeApp:commonMain: Could not resolve androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.5.1.
Required by:
    project :composeApp > androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

:composeApp:commonMain: Could not resolve androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.5.1.
Required by:
    project :composeApp > androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

I tried using an old version of 2.6.0, it passed sync but I couldn't import it in my program and use rememberNavController and NavHost as the guides describes.
Can anyone help me?

"I couldn't import it in my program and use rememberNavController and NavHost as the guides describes" -- note that those guides are for Compose for Android projects, and you are building a Compose Multiplatform project.

This is because you have different dependencies. please see the dependency provided by Kotlin officials. reference link
org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation:navigation-compose: // latest version


Check the dependency version: Ensure you’re using a compatible version of navigation-compose with your Compose Multiplatform project. The latest version available is 2.8.0-alpha10.
